error in rendering a RESTful comments in ejs
when working with ejs and render a file of comments contains username and comment it only renders the username and the comments is not rendering at all
index of comments
const comments = [
    {
        username:'memo' ,
        Comment:'ha ha ha hahaha'
    },
    {
        username:' makrom' ,
        Comment:'xy xy xy xyxyxyxyxyxy'
    },
    {
        username:'meno' ,
        Comment:'that is so funny'
    },
    {
        username:'mena' ,
        Comment:'here is a comment'
    }
]

app.get('/comments' , (req , res) => {
    res.render('comments/index' , { comments })
})

EJS
<% for (let c of comments){ %>
         <li> <%= c.username%> - <%=c.comment%></li>
<% } %>

expected to render the username and its comment but it only render the username

EJS is JavaScript, and JavaScript is case-sensitive.
As comment property is defined as Comment, you need to use the same form in the template, so not lowercase c.comment, which is undefined, and why it doesn't render, but the same form c.Comment (or change comment property to lowercase in comments array):
<% for (let c of comments){ %>
         <li> <%= c.username%> - <%=c.Comment%></li>
<% } %>

